# solving kakuro in prolog using predicate

Tags: prolog

I want to predicate solve Kakuro.
My kakuro is this
[image]

I have to  create a predicate using the word solve (solve/1) for the game kakuro. I tried 3-4 codes and all of them have errors. The variables have to be between 1-9(A value is between 1-9) and all the variables have to be different in one rows&columns(24=A+B+C not 24=A+A+C).

First code is:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
solve(L):-
    L= [A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P],
    all_different(L),
   L ins 1..9,
    A #= 24-B-C,
    B #= 26-F-J-N,
    C #= 15-G-K-O,
    E #= 11-F-G,
    E #= 17-A,
    J #= 22-K-L,
    N #= 14-O-P,
    L #= 13-P.
```

Second code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
sum_list([],0).
sum_list([Head|Tail], Sum):-sum_list(Tail, Sum1),Sum is Head+Sum1.

go:-
    Vars=[A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P],
    Vars ins 1..9,
    word([A,B,C],24),
    word([B,F,J,N],26),
    word([C,G,K,O],15), 
    word([E,F,G],11),
    word([A,E],17),
    word([J,K,L],22),
    word([N,O,P],14),   
    word([L,P],13),
    labeling(Vars),
    writeln(Vars).

word(L,Sum):-
sum_list(L,X),
X=:=Sum,
all_different(L).
```

Third code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
 kakuro(L):-
      L = [A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P],
      L ins 1..9,       
      Z1 = [A,B,C],
      all_different(Z1),
      A =:= 24-B-C,     
      Z2 = [B,F,J,N],
      all_different(Z2),
      B =:=26-F-J-N,
      Z3 = [C,G,K,O],
      all_different(Z3),
      C =:= 15-G-K-O,
      Z4 = [E,F,G],
      all_different(Z4),
      E =:= 11-F-G,
      Z5 = [A,E],
      all_different(Z5),
      E =:= 17-A,
      Z6 = [J,K,L],
      all_different(Z6),
      J =:=22-K-L,
      A1 = [N,O,P],
      all_different(A1),
      N =:= 14-O-P,
      A2 = [L,P],
      all_different(A2),
      L =:=13-P,
      labeling([], L).
```

Also how do I start the solving process? Will it be like: `?-solve(L).` ?? Also the `L ins 1..9` is not working.
[image]

Comment: @MaxB , I uploaded the photo of the kakuro i have to solve. I have to write a constraint solve/1 which have gives the solution of the kakuro.. I have the following constrants: 1) the variables have to be different in the line or column   2) the numbers (A=:= 24-B-C) have to be between  1-9 (like A has to be only 1 or 2... etc)

Comment: @MaxB i tried the codes that i wrote above but when i run it I get a lot of false.

Comment: The third version seems close to correct but you should use the operator `#=` instead of `=:=` (like in your first version).

Comment: `Xs ins 1..9` may not work in all versions of clpfd, depending on which prolog system you are using. SICStus, for instance, defines `domain(Xs,1,9)` instead.

Comment: @jnmonette when i use #= is not working i have more errors.. also how  should I call the predicate kakuro? I tried  ' ?- kakuro ([A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P]). ' and the error i have is : error unknown precedure:kakuro/1 (DWIM could not correct goal) ... also if i asked ?-kakuro. or  ?-kakuro(L).  or ?-kakuro([L]) or ?-kakuro. is the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a solution based on DuDa's, but using the `sum/3` constraint and delaying labeling to the end. This makes for a more efficient and more declarative solution.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

kakuro(Vars):-
    Vars=[A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P],
    Vars ins 1..9,
    word([A,B,C],24), 
    word([B,F,J,N],26),
    word([C,G,K,O],15), 
    word([E,F,G],11),
    word([A,E],17),
    word([J,K,L],22),
    word([N,O,P],14),   
    word([L,P],13),
    labeling([],Vars).

word(L,Sum):-
    all_different(L),
    sum(L,#=,Sum).
```

Answer (score 1):

At first before fixing the `ins`/`labeling` problem: there are issues with your code #1 and #3. In code #1 you state that all your variables need to have different values. This will not provide a valid solution. In code #1 and #3 you have used the variable `L` once as container for the variables and once as one element.

I have tested my code with [Swish](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). This is the code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sum_list([],0).
sum_list([Head|Tail], Sum):-
    sum_list(Tail, Sum1),
    Sum is Head+Sum1.

kakuro(Vars):-
    Vars=[A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P],
    Vars ins 1..9,
    word([A,B,C],24), 
    word([B,F,J,N],26),
    word([C,G,K,O],15), 
    word([E,F,G],11),
    word([A,E],17),
    word([J,K,L],22),
    word([N,O,P],14),   
    word([L,P],13),
    writeln(Vars).

word(L,Sum):-
    labeling([],L),
    all_different(L),
    sum_list(L,Sum).
```

This is the (only) output for `?- kakuro(L).`:

```
[9, 8, 7, 8, 2, 1, 9, 5, 8, 7, 2, 5]
```

At first you need to have the `ins/2` predicate running. This should work with SWI prolog. Second you know what to do with the `labeling/2` predicate. This one will set values given from their domain (given via `ins/2`) to the entry. In SWI Prolog the first attribute is a list of options, no need to worry. **AFTER** labeling your variables you can "test" them and put constraints on them. You can do the labeling once for all variables at the beginning but this is pretty slow because all your progress is lost. So I recommend to do it in the `word/2` predicate. If a dead end occurs the backtracking goes back to the `word/2` predicate and not to the beginning of the `kakuro/1` predicate.

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciate your help!! Have a good day:)